# Question about mountpoints

Tags: mount

Here's my `sdc` device with 3 differents partitions:

```
  sdc      8:32   0 223.6G  0 disk 
├─sdc1   8:33   0   571M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdc2   8:34   0  18.6G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sdc3   8:35   0 204.4G  0 part /
```

My question is, what happens to the original content of `sdc1` if e.g I mount it elsewhere like `/mnt` ? Are the content of `/boot/efi` deleted in the process?

I know I shouldn't do it but just wanna know what would happen.

Comment: @user68186 Sorry my knowledge is still very limited with Linux. If I understand it right, nothing is really stored on my `sdc` partitions, is that what you mean? The partitions allows me to see what's the content of a specific folder. But then where's the `/` stored? EDIT: I use Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @user68186 So if I remount `sdc1` to a random empty folder called `/test`, I'll be able to see the actual content of the partition which are the EFI files?

Comment: Yeah I think I get it now. But let's say I do that, my system won't be able to find the EFI files then, right? It would not know where the original content of `/boot/efi` is because now `/test` is the entry point of these files.

Comment: That is the reason not to fool around with sdc1.  System boots from sdc1(in your case) and if it can't find it, no loading of Ubuntu and/or other OSs.

Comment: Everybody is wrong... the /boot/efi partition is already mounted. Check your /etc/fstab.

Comment: @heynnema  think OP was thinking if he booted from USB and moved or change mount point, what would happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can mount `/dev/sdc1` anywhere you like, and nothing will happen to its contents unless you remove something from there using whatever mount point to access the partition.

Comment: Thanks, I think I figured it out now.

Comment: That's not right. The /boot/efi partition is already mounted. Check your /etc/fstab.

Comment: I can mount it elsewhere.